# What programming language was used to create Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, technology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which tools and technologies were used to build the Trilogy?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-were-used-to-build-the-trilogy)

What programming language was used to create Stack Overflow?

Comment: Functionally an exact a duplicate of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10372/is-stackoverflow-com-written-in-ruby-on-rails/10377#10377

Answer (score 12):

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/